# Changing the font family and size for a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

The default font family and size for Winform apps are just too small (and look so outdated IMHO).

Is there any easy way I could change them for the whole application? I'd prefer not to set them on a control or form basis -just a one time thing, if possible.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Short answer : no. But you can workaround this.

Make yourself a BaseForm that is empty and sets it's font to the one you want. Then you need to make every other form to inherits your base one.

Answer (score 17):

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `Font` property of the forms in your app, and this will change all child controls that have the same font.