# How to get Font Family list for specific language?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

**This how you get all the font families list:**

```
    List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

    foreach (FontFamily font in FontFamily.Families)
    {
            fonts.Add(font.Name);
    }
```

My site let users to write text with their own language.
Let say user pick arabic/hebrew language,I want to show him only the font family list availble for his language.
for example : 'Comic Sans MS' not support arabic/hebrew language.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254409/changing-the-font-family-and-size-for-a-winforms-app

Comment: May be this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod

Comment: also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604855/how-to-determine-which-fonts-contain-a-specific-character

Comment: if you consider windows 8 app. then see this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Language-font-mapping-919f08d4

Answer (score 0):

This code verifies whether a given font contains at least one character within the Unicode range of a specified language, such as Hebrew or Arabic. It's important to note that the function returns true if at least one Hebrew character is present, without confirming support for all language characters. Additionally, the function does not check for "Nikod" (נִיקוֹד) in Hebrew or Arabic characters.

```
    bool IsFontSupportsHebrew(string fontName)
    {
        // Define the Unicode range for Hebrew characters
        int hebrewStart = 0x0590;
        int hebrewEnd = 0x05FF;

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily(fontName), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
        GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;

        if (typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
        {
            IDictionary<int, ushort> characterToGlyphMap = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap;

            return characterToGlyphMap.Keys.Any(unicodeValue => unicodeValue >= hebrewStart && unicodeValue <= hebrewEnd);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to retrieve GlyphTypeface for {fontName}");
        }
    }
```

If you want to change to Arabic characters, you should alter or adjust the Unicode range to span from 0x0600 to 0x06FF.